# codepen demo is not working in local browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just stumbled upon a codepen [demo](http://codepen.io/timohausmann/pen/icCer). Then code works fine in codepen window. When, I copied it in a local HTML file it stopped working. Here is the code all combined in one .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
#myCanvas {
display: block;
}
#button {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 7px 20px;
left: 50%;
width: 200px;
margin-left: -100px;
top: 50%;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
background: hsla(260, 100%, 50%, 1);
cursor: pointer;

animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
transition: background 0.4s, border 0.2s, margin 0.2s;
}
#button:hover {
background: hsla(220, 100%, 60%, 1);
margin-top: -1px;
animation: none;
}
#button:active {
border-bottom-width: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
}
@keyframes pulse {
0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-top: 6px; 
}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
Math.randMinMax = function(min, max, round) {
var val = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
if( round ) val = Math.round( val );
return val;
};
Math.TO_RAD = Math.PI/180;
Math.getAngle = function( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
var dx = x1 - x2,
    dy = y1 - y2;
return Math.atan2(dy,dx);
};
Math.getDistance = function( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
var xs = x2 - x1,
    ys = y2 - y1;       
xs *= xs;
ys *= ys;
return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
};
var FX = {};
(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    lastUpdate = new Date(),
    mouseUpdate = new Date(),
    lastMouse = [],
    width, height;

FX.particles = [];

setFullscreen();
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', buttonEffect);

function buttonEffect() {

    var button = document.getElementById('button'),
        height = button.offsetHeight,
        left = button.offsetLeft,
        top = button.offsetTop,
        width = button.offsetWidth,
        x, y, degree;

    for(var i=0;i<40;i=i+1) {

        if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {

            y = Math.randMinMax(top, top+height);

            if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
                x = left;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(-45,45);
            } else {
                x = left + width;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(135,225);
            }

        } else {

            x = Math.randMinMax(left, left+width);

            if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
                y = top;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(45,135);
            } else {
                y = top + height;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(-135, -45);
            }

        }
        createParticle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            degree: degree,
            speed: Math.randMinMax(100, 150),
            vs: Math.randMinMax(-4,-1)
        });
    }
}
window.setTimeout(buttonEffect, 100); 

loop();

window.addEventListener('resize', setFullscreen );

function createParticle( args ) {

    var options = {
        x: width/2,
        y: height/2,
        color: 'hsla('+ Math.randMinMax(160, 290) +', 100%, 50%, '+(Math.random().toFixed(2))+')',
        degree: Math.randMinMax(0, 360),
        speed: Math.randMinMax(300, 350),
        vd: Math.randMinMax(-90,90),
        vs: Math.randMinMax(-8,-5)
    };

    for (key in args) {
      options[key] = args[key];
    }

    FX.particles.push( options );
}

function loop() {

    var     thisUpdate = new Date(),
        delta = (lastUpdate - thisUpdate) / 1000,
        amount = FX.particles.length,
        size = 2,
        i = 0,
        p;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(15,15,15,0.25)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

    ctx.globalCompositeStyle = 'lighter';

    for(;i<amount;i=i+1) {

        p = FX.particles[ i ];

        p.degree += (p.vd * delta);
        p.speed += (p.vs);// * delta);
        if( p.speed < 0 ) continue;

        p.x += Math.cos(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);
        p.y += Math.sin(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate( p.x, p.y );
        ctx.rotate( p.degree * Math.TO_RAD );

        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.fillRect( -size, -size, size*2, size*2 );

        ctx.restore();
    }

    lastUpdate = thisUpdate;

    requestAnimFrame( loop );
}

function setFullscreen() {
    width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};
})();
</script>
<button id="button">click me</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which browser your html code is not working? I also tested the same code on Fiddle.net and its working for me in firefox.

Comment: Firefox version 34. It is not working in any of three browsers that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your `script code` in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) LIKE,

```
$(function(){
   window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
       ....
       ....
   })();
});
```

As your script is loaded first but it doesn't find any DOM element, so it not works.

Also you don't need to include jquery, as you are not using any jquery functionality in your code so try it like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <style>
            // your style here
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <button id="button">click me</button>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script>
            // and no need to include jquery if not used
            // you script goes here after adding DOM elements
        </script>        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks its working. I have a doubt how could it work in your browser without writing anything additional but it required this extra code to work in mine.

Comment: It stopped working after removing the jQuery script. So, I included it again and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to put the script tags inside the `<head></head>` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
#myCanvas {
display: block;
}
#button {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 7px 20px;
left: 50%;
width: 200px;
margin-left: -100px;
top: 50%;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
background: hsla(260, 100%, 50%, 1);
cursor: pointer;

animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
transition: background 0.4s, border 0.2s, margin 0.2s;
}
#button:hover {
background: hsla(220, 100%, 60%, 1);
margin-top: -1px;
animation: none;
}
#button:active {
border-bottom-width: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
}
@keyframes pulse {
0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-top: 6px; 
}}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
Math.randMinMax = function(min, max, round) {
var val = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
if( round ) val = Math.round( val );
return val;
};
Math.TO_RAD = Math.PI/180;
Math.getAngle = function( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
var dx = x1 - x2,
    dy = y1 - y2;
return Math.atan2(dy,dx);
};
Math.getDistance = function( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
var xs = x2 - x1,
    ys = y2 - y1;       
xs *= xs;
ys *= ys;
return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
};
var FX = {};
(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    lastUpdate = new Date(),
    mouseUpdate = new Date(),
    lastMouse = [],
    width, height;

FX.particles = [];

setFullscreen();
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', buttonEffect);

function buttonEffect() {

    var button = document.getElementById('button'),
        height = button.offsetHeight,
        left = button.offsetLeft,
        top = button.offsetTop,
        width = button.offsetWidth,
        x, y, degree;

    for(var i=0;i<40;i=i+1) {

        if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {

            y = Math.randMinMax(top, top+height);

            if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
                x = left;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(-45,45);
            } else {
                x = left + width;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(135,225);
            }

        } else {

            x = Math.randMinMax(left, left+width);

            if( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
                y = top;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(45,135);
            } else {
                y = top + height;
                degree = Math.randMinMax(-135, -45);
            }

        }
        createParticle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            degree: degree,
            speed: Math.randMinMax(100, 150),
            vs: Math.randMinMax(-4,-1)
        });
    }
}
window.setTimeout(buttonEffect, 100); 

loop();

window.addEventListener('resize', setFullscreen );

function createParticle( args ) {

    var options = {
        x: width/2,
        y: height/2,
        color: 'hsla('+ Math.randMinMax(160, 290) +', 100%, 50%, '+(Math.random().toFixed(2))+')',
        degree: Math.randMinMax(0, 360),
        speed: Math.randMinMax(300, 350),
        vd: Math.randMinMax(-90,90),
        vs: Math.randMinMax(-8,-5)
    };

    for (key in args) {
      options[key] = args[key];
    }

    FX.particles.push( options );
}

function loop() {

    var     thisUpdate = new Date(),
        delta = (lastUpdate - thisUpdate) / 1000,
        amount = FX.particles.length,
        size = 2,
        i = 0,
        p;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(15,15,15,0.25)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

    ctx.globalCompositeStyle = 'lighter';

    for(;i<amount;i=i+1) {

        p = FX.particles[ i ];

        p.degree += (p.vd * delta);
        p.speed += (p.vs);// * delta);
        if( p.speed < 0 ) continue;

        p.x += Math.cos(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);
        p.y += Math.sin(p.degree * Math.TO_RAD) * (p.speed * delta);

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate( p.x, p.y );
        ctx.rotate( p.degree * Math.TO_RAD );

        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.fillRect( -size, -size, size*2, size*2 );

        ctx.restore();
    }

    lastUpdate = thisUpdate;

    requestAnimFrame( loop );
}

function setFullscreen() {
    width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">click me</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```